# Python: Is There a builtin that works similar but opposite to .index()?

Tags: python, built-in

Just a forewarning: I just recently started programming and Python is my first language and only language so far.

Is there a builtin that works in the opposite way of `.index()`? I'm looking for this because I made a bool function where I have a list of ints and I want to return `True` if the given list of ints is a list of powers of some int x of the form `[x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, ...]` and `False' otherwise.

What I want to say in code is along the lines of:

```
n >= 1  
while the position(n+1) = position(1)*position(n) 
    for the length of the list
    return True
otherwise 
    False.
```

Is there a builtin I could use to input the position and return the item in the list?

```
list = [1,2,4,8,16]
position(4)
```

returns the int 16.

EDIT: sorry I don't know how to format on here
ok ill show what I mean:

```
def powers(base):
''' (list of str) -> bool
Return True if the given list of ints is a list of powers of 
some int x of the form [x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, ...] and False 
otherwise.
>>> powers([1, 2, 4, 8]) 
True
>>> powers([1, 5, 25, 75])
False
'''
```

FINAL EDIT:

I just went through all of the available list methods from here (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and read the descriptions. What I'm asking for, isn't available as a list method :(

sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: How about `list[4]`? I would recommend reading through the basics, see e.g. http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: I tried that already but I can't make it general enough to apply for all items.

Comment: I'll check out the link though, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean *"general enough"*? Give a [mcve].

Comment: @Marco your comment makes no sense ...

Comment: `not list.index(X)` would be the oposite of `list.index`

Comment: Does my docstring make my problem more clear?

Comment: No. The literal answer to your question is `thing[index]` as shown above. If you've unsuccessfully *"tried that already"*, show a [mcve] of the code (not just the docstring) in which you did so. If you don't know how to format, read the help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My goal was to write the function using a while loop

Comment: ...OK? I don't see how that's at all relevant. Please learn [ask] and actually provide what you've repeatedly been asked for.

Comment: `powers([])` is `True`? or `False`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As an answer to:

> Is there a builtin I could use to input the position and return the item in the list?

You just need to access the `list` with it's index as:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,4,8,16]
>>> my_list[4]
16  # returns element at 4th index
```

And, this property is independent of language. All the languages supports this.

---

Based on your edit in the question, you may write your function as:

```
def check_value(my_list):
    # if len is less than 2
    if len(my_list) < 2:
        if my_list and my_list[0] == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False 
    base_val = my_list[1] # as per the logic, it should be original number i.e num**1 
    for p, item in enumerate(my_list):
        if item != base_val ** p: 
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

Sample run:

```
>>> check_value([1, 2, 4, 8])
True
>>> check_value([1, 2, 4, 9])
False
>>> check_value([1, 5, 25, 75])
False
```

Comment: There's likely a lot more to this than just indexing into the list.

Comment: But the question is specific to: *Is there a builtin I could use to input the position and return the item in the list?* Else is what OP is trying to achieve

Comment: lol alot more  huh? ... he says something along those lines in the comment but from what hes given us I would say this is the answer (although not really worthy of an answer)

Comment: `check_value([1])`

Comment: @JoranBeasley handled the edge scenario.

Comment: Obviously it could be optimised but considering the skill-set of OP, I want to keep this simple :

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make what I wanted, using this as a rough guide

Answer (score -1):

```
def powers(n):
    for i in itertools.count(0):
        yield n**i


def is_powers(li):
   if li[0] == 1:
      if len(li) > 1:
          return all(x==y for x,y in zip(li,powers(li[1])))
      return True
   return False

is_powers([1, 2, 4, 8])
is_powers([1, 5, 25, 75])
```

maybe ... its really not clear what you are asking...  this assumes that it always must start with a 1 if it is valid...