# how to check if items in list are power of any number in python?

Tags: python

I am not even sure how to start.
could anyone help me to write a code?

Comment: this must be a homework assignment ... see also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390902/python-is-there-a-builtin-that-works-similar-but-opposite-to-index

Comment: as an aside usually where you start is asking your professor or classmates for help ... (and making it to all the lectures)

Comment: This seems more like a math question than programming. Once you find out the mathematical process, coding it in Python should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously a begginer, so I will explain the code. Say we have a list with numbers 1,5,7,9 and 16.

```
mylist = [1,5,7,9,16]
```

Now we have to search through our numbers to find if they are squares.

```
for number in mylist:
    if math.sqrt(number)**2 == number:
        print(str(number) + " is a square number")
```

If you just run this code as is, it will output "Error: Math is not defined", you have to allow access to the *math* module. To do this, at the top of your code type:

```
import math
```

Now you can run it and it will output:

```
1 is a square number
9 is a square number
16 is a square number
```

Comment: He asked to find square numbers in a list, so that's what I did.